# Backup complete postgis database with geometry transformation

Tags: postgresql, postgis, database-backups

I have a PostGIS enabled PostgreSQL database that is no longer needed in production. I would like to back it up, but the geometry columns of PostGIS should be transformed to a simple, long-term stable text format like WKT.

I'm aware of the [`ST_AsText`](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#idm2192) function.

```
SELECT road_id, ST_AsText(road_geom) AS geom, road_name FROM roads;
```

But how do I apply this to backup the complete database with several tables with geometries and many without?

Comment: Would you have so many tables, that writing a script wouldn't be possible? In case there aren't that many, a `copy` statement would do the trick. Let me know if you need help with this.

Comment: btw, why exactly do you need the backup as `wkt`?

Comment: Yes, the default output format is EWKB, the Extended Well-Known Binary format. It is as good as EWKT.

Comment: @JimJones By writing a script you mean a set of select statements to pull the individual tables? Wkt is not necessary, but I'm familiar with it and I've seen that the transformation as already implemented in `ST_AsText()`.

Comment: @nevrome yes, I meant exactly it: write individual scripts for each table. Doing so you have the freedom to chose between many different geometry flavours, such as `wkt`, `geojson` or `gml`. Although for backup purposes I would still stick to `ewbk`.

Comment: But EWKB is not human readable, isn't it? And it's postgis specific, ja? So how can it be a good backup format? I don't want to transfer this database from one running system to the other. I want to achieve reliable, long term data storage.

Comment: I totally understand your concern. Well, I'm not sure if it is possible to change the output format for geometries, but in case you don't have many tables with geometries, I'd go for a solution like `CREATE TABLE roads2 AS SELECT road_id, ST_AsText(road_geom) AS geom, road_name FROM roads;`. In that way you would create a second table containing the geometries as WKT and so your backup. Not elegant, but perhaps okay for archival purposes.

Comment: Just let me know how you solved it... I'm now very curious!

Answer (score 0):

That's the backup strategy I finally applied:

**1. Normal dump of the PostGIS-Postgres database with pg_dump. Plain-text format to improve readability.**

**2. CSV backup of all tables**

For this I created a copy of my initial database ("la_as_text") and transformed all the geometry columns to text with the following script (thanks @Jim Jones). It's very specific for my case, but I decided to post it like this anyway. Just in case somebody runs in the came issues as I did with views that depend on geometry columns and gist indexes. The views won't work if you change the datatype to text and text columns are also not valid for gist indexing.

```
#!/bin/bash

# has to be run by a user who has owner permissions for the database

rm delete_views.txt delete_views_mod.txt alter_script.txt alter_script_mod.txt

# delete all views - not necessary in long-term-backup and cause problems when altering geometry columns 
echo "select 'drop view ' ||table_name|| ';' from information_schema.views where table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') and table_name "'!'"~ '^pg_';" | psql la_as_text >> delete_views.txt

cat delete_views.txt | tail -n +3 | head -n -2 >> delete_views_mod.txt

cat delete_views_mod.txt | psql la_as_text

# delete one particular gist index that depends on a geometry column -- text can't be indexed with gist 
echo "drop index idx_combined_points_the_geom;" | psql la_as_text

# change data type geometry (EWKB) to human readable text (WKT)
echo "select 'alter table '||table_schema||'.'||table_name||' alter column '||column_name||' type text USING ST_AsText('||column_name||');' from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'public' and udt_name = 'geometry';" | psql la_as_text >> alter_script.txt

cat alter_script.txt | tail -n +3 | head -n -2 >> alter_script_mod.txt

cat alter_script_mod.txt | psql la_as_text
```

The resulting database lacks a lot of its initial functionality due to the missing geometry data type, but it's human readable.

Instead of a normal dump I exported all the individual tables as ';'-separated text files with the following [script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137140/how-can-i-dump-all-tables-to-csv-for-a-postgresql-schema):

```
#!/bin/bash

SCHEMA="public"
DB="la_as_text"

psql -Atc "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname='$SCHEMA'" $DB |\
  while read TBL; do
    psql -c "copy $SCHEMA.$TBL to stdout with csv delimiter ';'" $DB > $TBL.csv
  done
```

I'm pretty confident that this backup can be reconstructed in the future -- if necessary.